# criteria query fails group by because of single qoutes?

Tags: java, group-by, jpa-2.0, criteria

I came accross an interesting behaviour: probably criteria API puts single quotes around parameters in query.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<SomeClass> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(SomeClass.class);
Metamodel metamodel = em.getMetamodel();
EntityType<SomeClass> entityType_ = metamodel.entity(SomeClass.class);
Root<SomeClass> root = criteriaQuery.from( SomeClass );
criteriaQuery.select(root.get(entityType_.getSingularAttribute( "someField" ));  
TypedQuery<SomeClass> q = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<SomeClass> result = (List<SomeClass>) q.getResultList();
```

this snippet results in a list with one column which is full of with "someField" in every single cells of the column. (select 'someField' from SomeClass;  <--really works )

The select accepts this behaviour by criteria, however the group by fails, says: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.
I only think about criteria does the same substitution, like in case of select.

```
criteriaQuery.groupBy(root.get(entityType_.getSingularAttribute("someField") ));
```

How can I avoid those single qoutes in my queries?

Any suggests appreciated, thank You in advance.

Comment: JPA deals with Entity java objects and maps them to fields in the database.  If there is a problem with how the field is written out in the query, you will need to check how you have mapped it.  Please show the orm.xml or annotations used to map the SomeClass entity, particularly the someField attribute/property.

Comment: @Entity
@Table(name="T$SOMECLASS")
public class SomeClass implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @ListColumn(colNameKey = "ID", colNum = 0 )
 private long Id;
 @ListColumn(colNameKey = "Név", colNum = 1 )
 private String nev;
 ...
}

Comment: and the used annotation interface is :
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ListColumn {
 int colNum();
 String colNameKey();
 HorizontalAlignment hAlign() default HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
 VerticalAlignment vAlign() default VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
 int fontSize() default 10;
 String fontType() default "arial";
 String fontStyle() default "normal";

}

Comment: Is nev the attribute used in your query?  Other than the entity and table annotations, you haven't shown JPA mappings.  Are you using provider specific or letting JPA default the mappings?  For example, how does it know what the pk is?

Comment: There is a @Id annotation on getId() method in the class. I am using default mapping. I think only these rows are relevant to mapping in persistence :
<properties>
 <property name="org.hibernate.SQL.level" value="FINEST"/>
 <property name="org.hibernate.type.level" value="FINEST"/>
</properties>